# How I use Google Analytics to produce a report for each franchise (on a subdomain)?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using one tracking code on a website for a franchise company with 122 franchises. Each franchise has it's own subdomain, ie: city.franchisecompany.com - the main "All website data" view shows me everything, but I also need to report on each individual franchisee.

I've began this set up using a view with the filter:

```
Include Only -> Traffic to the hostname -> That contains -> city
```

However, I can only set up 25 of these. How can I get more? Or is there a better way to achieve this set up other than views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up Custom Reports in Google Analytics. You can create custom reports for each Domain, or you can group domains together. After creating custom reports, you can send them to yourself automatically.

Alternatively, you can set up to 25 custom views. If you have more than 100 sub domains, you could always set up views for a few domains and filter your Custom Reports within those views for the specific sub domain.

Once your Custom Reports are configured, you can set up automatic monthly emails.

To set up views, view the [guide here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en).

To create Custom Reports, view [this guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en).